# Yes, use nice Spanish onion

Tags: grammar

**Reporter**: I’m here with Carlos in his fruit and vegetable
store and Carlos is going to help me make a salad. Carlos,
could you start up picking out some vegetables.

**Seller**: OK. Yes, **use nice Spanish onion**.

**Reporter**: Spanish onions, of course we always need that.

**Seller**: Nice red pepper.

**Reporter**: Aha, a red pepper.

---

**Seller**: OK. Yes, **use nice Spanish onion**.

Is it an **imperative sentence** or a **declarative Sentence**"?

Thank you

Comment: 'Seller' Carlos is having trouble with his articles. He should say 'use **a** nice Spanish onion' and '**a** nice red pepper'.

Comment: As written, it's imperative, but is the seller really trying to command the reporter? Probably not. The seller probably means something like, "Let's use a nice Spanish onion," or "Why don't you use a nice Spanish onion?"

Comment: Hello again @rezaellstack  This is your regular reminder that the old tv program that you watch to learn English is a very very poor source.  It contains much that is odd and much that is wrong.  Please find a better way to study.  This TV program will just make it harder for you to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an imperative.  But don't read too much into that.  I'd assume Carlos is a non-native speaker. He speaks broken English with grammatical errors.

Carlos probably means something like "We'll use this nice Spanish onion." This mistake doesn't really affect understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much, James